# Numpy extracting data in one column versus another

Tags: python, numpy, csv, file

I have the following problem with extracting data in one column versus another.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import genfromtxt
df = genfromtxt('data.csv', delimiter=",")
data1 = []
data2 = []
data3 = []   
for i in range(150):
    if df[i,4] == 0:
        data1 += df[i,0]
    elif df[i,4] == 1:
        data2 += df[i, 0]
    else:
        data3 += df[i, 0]
```

```
df is in the form
[[4.9 3.  1.4 0.2 0. ]
[6.2 2.2 4.5 1.5 1. ]
.
.
.
[6.5 2.9 1.5 6.5 2. ]]
```

The solution does not work at all and is there an easier way to bypass the loop?

Comment: What is the intention behind the use of `+=` to assign to your lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = np.array([[4.9, 3., 1.4, 0.2, 0.],
               [6.2, 2.2, 4.5, 1.5, 1.],
               [6.3, 2.3, 4.7, 1.8, 1.],
               [6.5, 2.9, 1.5, 6.5, 2.]])

data1 = list(df[df[:, 4] == 0, 0])
data2 = list(df[df[:, 4] == 1, 0])
data3 = list(df[np.isin(df[:, 4], (0, 1), invert=True), 0])

print(data1, data2, data3, sep='\n')
```

Prints:

```
[4.9]
[6.2, 6.3]
[6.5]
```